# Can I make a change in propietary war file?

Tags: deployment, jar, war

I have a proprietary application and its war file is available to us. I need to basically add a jsp page to the current application. 
I was thinking i will write the independent jsp, java files build a war and add it to the proprietary war file.

Or

i will write the jsp, java files and add it to the same war.

Can i make a new war and make the proprietory to interact..
Which option is better.

Comment: Depending on what kind of proprietary application you have there you should consult their licensing terms first. It may be illegal to modify the existing war file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could unpack the war, then add your jsp. After that, re-build the war file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just unpack the war and add your custom content. Your libraries go in WEB-INF/lib and your classes in WEB-INF/classes. You can also add servlets, filters, and listeners to web.xml as needed.